# MacBook Pro Mojave, Android Pie, Android Device is recognized by adb but is not recogniced by Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

why isnt my device detected in Android Studio?

[image: System Information]

[image: ScreenShot]

[image: ScreenShot]

i can detect it in adb

```
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$ adb devices
List of devices attached
ce091829e258a11b04      device

Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$ adb shell
dreamlte:/ $ exit
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$
```

but i cant detect it in Android Studio which makes debugging (and logcat'ing) very difficult as i do not know how to correctly emulate what would normally happen in android studio, on the command line using adb

for example

```
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$ adb install app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$ # somehow start the application automagically
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$ # obtain application pid so i can filter in adb logcat
```

this is my current env for MacBook Pro

```
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$ env
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/pf/mtx5w525003d7dt_smftxd9h0000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.N5KLQm0rqw/Render
USER=mac
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.cat00ijzkS/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:15
PATH=/usr/local/ActiveGo-1.8.3/bin:/Users/mac/ActiveGo/bin:/usr/local/ActiveGo-1.8.3/gopath/bin:/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669:/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools:/Users/mac/bin:/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/KomodoIDE/12.0/XRE/state
TERMINAL_EMULATOR=JetBrains-JediTerm
PWD=/Users/mac/AndroidStudioProjects/AudioTester
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/mac
LOGNAME=mac
LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8
GOPATH=/Users/mac/ActiveGo:/usr/local/ActiveGo-1.8.3/gopath
_=/usr/bin/env
```

and this is my current env for Android

```
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$ adb shell
dreamlte:/ $ env
_=/system/bin/env
ANDROID_DATA=/data
LOGNAME=shell
HOME=/
ANDROID_STORAGE=/storage
TERM=xterm-256color
TERMINFO=/system/etc/terminfo
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1
ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
SHELL=/system/bin/sh
BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core-oj.jar:/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okhttp.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/framework-oahl-backward-compatibility.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec
MC_AUTH_TOKEN_PATH=/efs
ANDROID_SOCKET_adbd=12
HOSTNAME=dreamlte
EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/sdcard
ANDROID_CACHE=/cache
USER=shell
TMPDIR=/data/local/tmp
PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin
SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH=/system/framework/org.lineageos.platform.jar:/system/framework/org.lineageos.hardware.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar
ANDROID_ROOT=/system
DOWNLOAD_CACHE=/data/cache
dreamlte:/ $ exit
Macs-MacBook-Air:AudioTester mac$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your envirnment variables and make sure that ANDROID_HOME is set to proper directories